# Knockout js external template from a MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a Knockout js viewModel and want to use external templates to get an MVC 4 razor (cshtml) bound page so the initial page can be created on the server or bound through Knockout, I'll decide at runtime. I want to pass the name of the template to the controller like this (/Templates/KnockoutTemplate?templateName='gauge') where 'gauge' is the name of a view (radial.tmpl.cshtml) and have Knockout put it in the template block.

My Controller:

```
public class TemplatesController : Controller
{
     public TemplatesViewModel viewModel { get; set; }
     public TemplatesController()
     {
        this.viewModel = new TemplatesViewModel { Heading = "Radial" };
     }

    public ActionResult KnockoutTemplate(string templateName)
    {
        // is this right?
        return  PartialView(templateName, this.viewModel);
    }
}
```

radial.cshtml

```
   @model MVC4.Models.TemplatesViewModel
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Radial Template";
    }
    <div id="radialDashboardWidget" class="dashboardWidget" style="width: 100%">
     <h4 class="bold">@Model.Heading </h4>
     <!-- or I can do this, I'll decide at development time  -->
     <h4 class="bold" data-bind="text:heading"></h4>
    </div>
```

main page

```
<div id="dashboardWidgets" data-bind="foreach: Widgets" class="flexible-widget">
 <!-- ko template: {name: Properties.templateName  } -->
 <!-- /ko -->
 <div class="clear" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered this here: http://geekswithblogs.net/Aligned/archive/2012/08/17/knockout-js-and-external-mvc-cshtml-templates.aspx

My Controller:

```
public class TemplatesController : Controller
{
    public TemplatesViewModel viewModel { get; set; }

    public ActionResult KnockoutTemplate(string templateName)
    {
        return  PartialView(templateName.Replace("/", string.Empty), this.viewModel);
    }
}
```

radial.cshtml

```
@model MVC4.Models.TemplatesViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Radial Template";
}

<div id="radialDashboardWidget" class="dashboardWidget" style="width: 100%">
    <h4 class="bold" data-bind="text:@Model.Heading"></h4>
    <!-- add more HTML -->
</div>
```

Dashboard page with Knockout

```
<div id="dashboardWidgets" data-bind="foreach: Widgets" class="flexible-widget">
    <!-- ko template: {name: Properties.templateName  } -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <div class="clear" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve. In your cshtml you're 'binding' against the server-side Model object instead of an observable property of a client-side JavaScript object. You're not using Knockout there. Please post the Javascript which gets the Widgets-object so we can help you.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it to make it to try and make it more clear. I want to be able to use either approach and still load a template with the external template library for KO. I have a way forward, I just need to get around blogging it and I'll add the link here.